# How to do this question that talks about dependency of x

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let $x > 0$. Prove that the value of the following expression doesn't  depend on x

$$\int_{0}^{x} \frac{1}{1+t^2} dt + \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{x}} \frac{1}{1+t^2}dt$$

Attempt:

Left: f'(x) = $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$

Right: f'(x) = $\frac{1}{1+(\frac{1}{x})^2} -\frac{1}{x^2}$

$= \frac{1}{(1+\frac{1}{x^2})} - \frac{1}{x^2}$

$=\frac{x^2}{1+x^2} - \frac{1}{x^2}$

$=\frac{x^4 - x^2 - 1}{1+x^2}$

Yeah I don't know what I am doing, I tried to remove the integral but failed miserably

Comment: You have an equation, which is not an expression and doesn't have value.  Are you sure you've copied the problem correctly?

Comment: The = sign should be replaced by +.

Comment: Sorry I wrote the question wrong, yeah it should be + , thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question as-is after having been heavily edited, let for $x \gt 0\,$:

$$f(x) = \int_{0}^{x} \frac{1}{1+t^2} dt + \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{x}} \frac{1}{1+t^2}dt$$

Then, using the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Variable_limits_form):

$$
f'(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2} \,-\, \frac{1}{x^2} \cdot \frac{1}{1+ \cfrac{1}{x^2}} = \frac{1}{1+x^2} \,-\, \frac{1}{1+x^2} \,=\, 0 
$$

Thus $f'(x)=0\,$, so $f(x)$ is a constant, and therefore does not depend on $x$.

P.S. Note to the OP:

> Right: f'(x) = $\frac{1}{1+(\frac{1}{x})^2} -\frac{1}{x^2}$

This looks like you attempted to use Leibniz' rule, but misapplied it. The $-\,\frac{1}{x^2}$ derivative of the upper bound is *multiplied* with, not added to, the end value of the function being integrated.

Comment: Thank you. This was the solution I was looking for, everything else confused me.

Comment: @user349557 Glad it helped. For good measure, the other posted answers are all correct as well, yet this looked to me like the more direct way to get it done.

Comment: Wasn't saying they were not correct. Just have not learned any of the concepts in the way they did it.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\int_0^x \frac{1}{1+t^2}\,dt=\arctan(x)$.

Recalling $\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\arctan(x)+\arctan(1/x)=\pi/2\text{sgn(x)}}\,\,$, we see that the term of interest depends only on the sign of $x$.

---

From the pre-edited question

$$\arctan(x)=\arctan(1/x)\implies \arctan(x)=(\pi/4)\text{sgn}(x)\implies x=1\,\,\text{or}\,\,x=-1$$

Comment: I know that this equals zero? Does that prove dependency?

Comment: @Dr.MV Isn't it $\arctan(x)+\arctan(1/x) = \frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: @JackyChong Yes, correct.

Comment: @Dr.MV Could you also update your post.

Comment: arctan(x)+arctan(1/x)=π/2 . So yeah uhm, I was looking at tan identites, I cant find this one? Why is it pi/2

Comment: @user349557 I've edited to clarify.

Comment: @JackyChong I've edited the typo and added to the solution.

Comment: What does sgn stand for?

Comment: @user349557 It is the [sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function)

Answer (score 0):

Using the $u$ sub $t' = t^{-1}$, we see  $dt'= -(t')^2dt$ that
\begin{align}
\int^{\frac{1}{x}}_0\frac{1}{1+t^2}\ dt = -\int^x_\infty \frac{1}{1+(t')^{-2}} \frac{dt'}{(t')^2}= \int^\infty_x \frac{1}{1+(t')^2}\ dt' = \frac{\pi}{2} - \int^x_0\frac{1}{1+(t')^2}\ dt'. 
\end{align}

But we see that
\begin{align}
\frac{\pi}{2} - \int^x_0\frac{1}{1+(t')^2}\ dt'= \int^x_0\frac{1}{1+(t')^2}\ dt'
\end{align}
provided
\begin{align}
\int^x_0\frac{1}{1+(t')^2}\ dt' = \frac{\pi}{4}.
\end{align}
Thus, your claim is incorrect since equality holds only when $x=1$.

Comment: I have not learned improper integrals yet. So I have no idea how to understand in this way.

Comment: Jackie, $x=-1$ is also a solution.  You're tacitly assuming that $x>0$

Answer (score 0):

In the second integral, let $t=1/u$ to get

$$\int_0^{1/x}\frac1{1+t^2}\ dt=\int_x^\infty\frac1{1+(1/u)^2}\frac{du}{u^2}=\int_x^\infty\frac1{1+u^2}\ du$$

Add it to the first integral to get

$$I=\int_0^\infty\frac1{1+t^2}\ dt=\frac\pi2$$

which does not depend on $x$.